# Is Mist Wallet a node on the Ethereum network?

Tags: mist, nodes

I am new to Ethereum.  I've just installed the Mist Wallet, and I find that it keeps the CPU running HOT.  Is the wallet a node on the Ethereum Network?  If so, should I be able to mine stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the Mist wallet you run a node.

> I find that it keeps the CPU running HOT

The reason should be that your wallet is syncing to the blockchain.

> should I be able to mine stuff?

I've made my small research and I haven't found any proofs that you can mine using the Mist Wallet and have a reward for your work. People suggest connecting to mining pools and using software like Claymore or Ethermine if you actually want to mine and be rewarded.

---

[Ethereum Reddit similar question.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6f1mxx/i_have_the_mist_wallet_how_do_i_start_mining_with/) 
[From Beginner's Guide to Ethereum Mining in 2017 - How to Mine Ethereum on Your PC.](https://99bitcoins.com/guide-ethereum-mining-how-to-mine-ethereum/)